# Laravel 4: Generate language files with google translator

Tags: php, laravel-4, google-translate, lang

I am already having my site in english with language files inside "en" folder. Now i want to provide multiple language option for user.

For that i need to have "cn" folder for china language. To make it, i need to convert each file in google translator.

Any faster way to generate new language files to the new language?

Using google translator or any other option availble for this? Any help?

Comment: You COULD use the Google Translate API and iterate over your strings, but it really depends on the amount of strings you need to translate.

Comment: there is also a package for this try looking here http://packalyst.com/s/translate